# Why JB isn't doing accurate CMP

Tags: assembly, emu8086

In emu8086, I have written this code

```
include 'emu8086.inc'

org 100h

MOV AX,-1  
CMP AX,0
JB case1 

case2:
    printn 'This line should not be displayed'

case1:
    print 'I want this line'

ret
```

It is supposed to be printed only the case 1, but in this case output is showing both the cases. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [How to compare a signed value and an unsigned value in x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27284895)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JB` (Jump if Below) is used for unsigned integers which is similar to `JNAE` (Jump if Not Above or Equal).

So, if you want to compare with a signed integer (in your case -1), you have to use `JL` (Jump if Less) or `JNGE` (Jump if Not Greater or Equal)

Comment: that helped, thanks

Comment: `jb` is not only "similar" to `jnae`. It's alias of the **same** machine instruction (same binary opcode). And both are aliases of `jc`, which I personally think about as "base" alias, because it covers the flag which is being tested, while the `jb / jnae` are just comparison-helper aliases, but that's definitely just my opinion.